# Empty Set using filter startswith

Tags: django, python-3.x

Here's my model:

```
class Student(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    student_id = models.IntegerField()
    grade = models.IntegerField()
```

I imported the data from Excel. I want to use `Student.object.filter(name___istartswith = "Some String" )` , but I can't because every `Student.name` instance as "\xa0" before it.

I've tried:

`.filter(name___contains= "Some String")` works (but is not what I need)

Replacing "\xa0" with `s.name.replace("\xa0",'')` did...nothing. The "\xa0" returned!

```
.filter(name___istartswith = u"Some String")
```

Every time I run `Student.objects.filter(name__istarts with = "Some String")` an empty set is returned.

I'm sure it's something dumb, but what am I doing wrong? (Running python 3.5)

Comment: What is `_` exactly?

Comment: Shouldn't you use `'_'` instead of `_`, normally `_` is a function in Django used for translations.

Comment: @JonClements Sorry, that was for whatever term I was searching for

Comment: Edited for clarity!

Comment: Maybe a dumb question ... Wouldn't a better approach be to serialize/normalize the data before saving it to Student? That way you don't have to do this post-processing?